# Simplest way to grab echo from PHP file and use it in Android Studio project?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

In android studio project I am creating an app that has a login feature. The PHP page used connects to a database and has a select statement with POST variables. if the variables "username" and "password" are both in one row in the table then that means the user has access, thus an echo of "Success" is returned.

I am wondering if from within the main activity I can create statements that essentially will read "if the php file echos "Success" then startActivity of the next page. I believe i need HTTPURLClient, however, is there a way to "retreive" the echo from the php file in a short few lines and set the echo equal to a string variable in java so I can do a comparison if statement to see if it is "success"? Most HTTPClient tutorials are pages of code to connect

Comment: It would be better if you do some research on your topic before asking in stack overflow.  Please check this out https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I used this library https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask.
The basic format of the code using this library is this:

```
HashMap post = new HashMap();
post.put("txtName", variablename); // the first argument is the column name in your html file that refers to the username
post.put("txtPass", variablepass);// the first argument is the column name in your html file that refers to the password
PostResponseAsyncTask readData = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, post,
    new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            //s is the value that you get from the php execution so if you want to check for the word success you say:
       if(s.equals("success")){
           //do something
          }
        }
    });
readData.execute("http://yoursite.com/getdata.php");
```

Please refer to the link for more.